# git push edit for old commit

Tags: git, push

suppose that i have commit 1 - commit 2 - commit 3 - commit 4 .
than when i work i noticed that i have a problem on commit 3 and commit 4 put i don't wanna delete them - so i back to commit 2 and make some work and committed with message last_commit - the problem is when i push it i get this message

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.com:mo****/*******'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: You say you don't want to delete commit 3 and 4, yet you do so. So what is it that you actually wanna achieve?

Comment: Commits are immutable.

Comment: While commits can be [amended](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit), there are implications if the commit has been pushed (the commit documentation has more to read on this).

Comment: You can't achieve such a thing with git. Each last commit is parent to the next one. You cannot insert a commit in between without rewriting history. If you think there is something wrong in commit 3. Fix it in commit 5.